# Inline select new in LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

I have this standard piece of LINQ

```
var sidEvents = (from f in AppDelegate.Self.Subscription.Fred
                                          from s in f.Sid
                                          from e in s.Eve
                                          where e.date >= oneWeek
                                          select new {Title = e.type, Data = e.data, Date = e.date}).ToList();
```

I've changed a few things and now I get a list of Eve objects with the where condition after it like this

```
var sidEvents = AppDelegate.Self.DBManager.GetListOfEvents("type", "EatingOut").Where(t => t.date >= oneWeek).ToList();
```

Is there a way that I can extend this LINQ query to include the select new {...} that was on the original LINQ query?

Comment: putting .Select before the tolist doesn't work?

Comment: Nope - Select(new {...}).ToList(); gives me an error that I cannot convert an anonymous function to Func<Events, >

Comment: @Nodoid, your syntax is wrong, it should be `Select(e => new {...}).ToList()`, you gotta give it a function. `new {}` is a statement and cannot by any means be parsed into a function :)

Comment: @flindeberg - thanks - I usually use the (from f in ...) form of the query

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
var sidEvents = AppDelegate.Self.DBManager.GetListOfEvents("type", "EatingOut")
                    .Where(t => t.date >= oneWeek)
                    .Select(e => new { Title = e.type, Data = e.data, Date = e.date }).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you are looking for this:

```
var sidEvents = AppDelegate.Self.DBManager.GetListOfEvents("type", "EatingOut")
                   .Where(t => t.date >= oneWeek)
                   .Select(e => new {...})
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are more familiar with the LINQ query syntax, you can

- translate the second query from method syntax to query syntax

  ```
  var sidEvents = (from t in AppDelegate.Self.DBManager.GetListOfEvents("type", "EatingOut")
                   where t.date >= oneWeek
                   select t).ToList();
  ```
- and then replace the `select t` part with your `new` expression.